# How to architecture backbonejs application - click event on each table row backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am developing a application in which one of my template renders a table with n number of rows. Now in each row, i have a column with buttons like edit and delete.

When clicked on edit, a edit form appears in the same window in some div. That form needs to be populated with values fetched from backend.

Now nothing great in this. 
My problem is this:

I have a view which renders the complete table using the following template structure:

```
<script type="text/template" id="ledgersing"> 

 <div class="span6 widget"> 
 <div class="widget-header"> 
 <span class="title">Ledgers</span> 
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="addLedgerButton">Add Ledger</button> 
</div> 

 <div class="widget-content"> 

 <table width="100%" class="table table-striped dataTable"> 
 <thead> 
 <tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Action</th></tr> 
 </thead> 
<tbody> 
<% _.each(ledgers,function(data){ %>
<tr>
    <td><%= data.name %></td>
    <td><%= data.email %></td>
    <td><%= data.contact_number %></td>
    <td><span onClick="alert(<%= data.id %>)">x</span></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
</tbody>

</table> 
</div> 

 </div> 


 </div >
 </script>
```

In this it just alerts a id when clicked on x. Now do i need to necessarily use onClick event like this? I mean that i will need the id in whatever construct i use for processing. What can be a better solution? I know backbonejs can handle this mess with ease if application is structured properly. 
So essentially i want to know from experts, what will they do in such a scenario. How will they structure the application? I am novice to this frontend framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `_.each` in your templates, I'd go with one view per table row as each one has some bit of complexity (edit, delete)

In these view, you use the `events` hash to register your DOM events. Never use `onclick` in your HTML, this is a really bad practice.

Don't hesitate to look at the [TodoMVC Backbone example](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone) for ideas on how to organize your app.

Comment: One quick question: i will have lots of templates views etc. as i can foresee. My fear is that application will be really heavy if i load all the template code, view code at the onset. Need your suggestions on that as well.

Comment: Well, you can put your templates in external files and load them via Ajax. You may want to checkout [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) for more detail on how to structure your app.

Comment: can you provide a example of loading template with ajax?

Comment: You just need to use basic [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) _(may need to set `dataType` to "text" if you work directly from files without any server)_

Comment: Consider using Yeoman < http://yeoman.io > to get an AMD supported backbone boilerplate running.  Once you have this, you can load your templates with Require.js.  This will load them via ajax for local dev, but will provide you with build scripts to combine the templates into your JS for production.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I have decided to separate the view for each row. But what do i fix up as tagname? a tr?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing a backbone application for the first time and went thru exactly the same mistake.

I first I just tried to translate my php / asp / ruby / whatever_server_side_template_technology into underscore templates, and got something pretty much like what you had.

Now I can realize it's a mistake. You should use subviews. The events and the associated model will be connected to that subview. Pretty soon you'll have lots of view listening to events and updating themselves when data changes, but if you're carefull it will be ok.

Here's a demo app I'm working on: https://bb-jugar.rhcloud.com/index.html#Wine
and here's the github repo: https://github.com/opensas/BackboneBootstrap

This is how I solved it: https://github.com/opensas/BackboneBootstrap/blob/master/demoapp/js/src/views/crud/RowsView.js

Comment: yes correct. I created separate views for each row way back. thanks.